Spring Boot Security Logout not working. How can I fix it?
I'm learning about Spring Security Filter Chain. And I'm trying to implement authentication. The problem I'm encountering is that when I log out from the website, the JSESSIONID is not removed from browser, and I'm able to make requests without logging in again. Here is My SecurityConfig.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private final UserSecurityService userSecurityService;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider daoProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userSecurityService);
        return provider;
    }
}

So I searched for solutions and came across this solution. With this code, the JSESSIONID is successfully removed with logout request. However, it's still allowing me to make requests without the JSESSIONID.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private final UserSecurityService userSecurityService;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.done")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider daoProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userSecurityService);
        return provider;
    }
}

When I test it with Postman, I'm required to include username and password as Basic Auth in every request, if they're not included, I get 401 unauthorized. (Which I'm not sure is the correct behavior)
Thank you for reading my question. I'll appreciate any help you can give.

Your code looks very inconsistent, there are points you should correct:

.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS with this you are indicating that there should not be sessions to maintain the state of authentication of users, this is used only when using JWT(JSON WEB TOKEN) in your case you should not apply this policy because the state of the users is maintained on the server.

You are configuring the logout mechanism.
also invalidating a session
.invalidateHttpSession(true); which is not done because there is no session in the server.


Your code could look like this:
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login") 
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true) 
              .permitAll()) 
            .logout(logout -> logout
               .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")  
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
              )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED));
        return http.build();
    }

This SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED policy creates sessions when necessary and also sets a path which users will access to login (/login) in case of a successful redirect to (/home) and this is allowed for all users.
